# Прием и отправка файла через один сокет

Tags: android, сокет, filestream

Так уж получилось, что сервак принемает файл и отдает мне через один порт...

В первом случае передача проходит успешно по ответам сервака:

```
SocketAddress SocketAdres = new InetSocketAddress(Server, FilePort);
socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.connect(SocketAdres);
FileChannel fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r").getChannel();
fileChannel.transferTo(0, fileChannel.size(), socketChannel);
socketChannel.close();
fileChannel.close();
```

Чуть дальше у нас начинаются проблемы :

```
int Size = Integer.parseInt(Answer);
File file2 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/download/" + "Dowland.db");
file2.createNewFile();
SocketAddress DataImport = new InetSocketAddress(Server, FilePort);
socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(DataImport);
socketChannel.connect(DataImport);
RandomAccessFile ra= new   RandomAccessFile(file2,"rw");
FileChannel fileChannel = ra.getChannel();
fileChannel.transferFrom(socketChannel, 0, Size);
socketChannel.close();
fileChannel.close();
```

Если сделать то я получаю вот это :

```
Caused by: java.nio.channels.AlreadyConnectedException
```

, не взирая на закрытие канала...

Вот в этой строке:
socketChannel.connect(DataImport);

Если пытаться в общем все делать через один и тот socketChannel, то у нас ничего не происходит вообще...

Учитывая опыт предыдущих проблем - разрешение на инет и запись, считывания внешнего хранилища у нас есть.

pls help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очередная не внимательная ошибка:

```
socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(DataImport);
```

Этой командой мы уже подключились, а мы пытаемся ещё раз:

```
socketChannel.connect(DataImport);
```

её нужно убрать